# Using a Teradata UDF in SAS Implicit Sql Pass Thru

Tags: sql, sas, teradata, user-defined-functions

I  am   trying to use  a Teradata  UDF (User Defined Function)  in a SAS Implicit SQL which establishes the connection to  Teradata using LIBNAME  Statement.Assume  that  the function is called PTY_DECRYPT and is defined in a Database called TEST in Teradata. The Purpose  of this function  is to decrypt values in a Column of a View in Teradata.

What   works  is using the UDF  in an Explicit  Sql .Below  I am using the function on a column called SSN_NBR in a view called V_TEST_PERS present in the Database called SAMPLE.

**Explcit Sql:**

```
Options  debug=DBMS_TIMERS sastrace=',,,d'
sastraceloc=saslog no$stsuffix fullstimer;


Proc Sql;
Connect to TERADATA(User=XXXXX pwd=XXXXX server=XXXXX);
Create Table Final as
select  *  from connection to teradata
(
Select
sub_id, 
SSN_NBR,
TEST.PTY_DECRYPT(SSN_NBR,'T_ssn_test',400,0,0 ) as SSN_NBR_Decrypt
from SAMPLE.V_TEST_PERS
);
disconnect from teradata;
Quit;
```

But  I would like to use the same function in an Implicit SQL but  it does not work.  Any ideas as to how  to make it work in an Implicit Sql with minimum  changes to the Implicit SQL?

**Implicit Sql**

```
Options  debug=DBMS_TIMERS sastrace=',,,d'
sastraceloc=saslog no$stsuffix fullstimer;

Libname Td Teradata  User=XXXXX pwd=XXXXX server=XXXXX database=SAMPLE ;

Proc sql;
Create  table Final as
select
sub_id, 
SSN_NBR,
TEST.PTY_DECRYPT(SSN_NBR,'T_ssn_test',400,0,0 ) as SSN_NBR_Decrypt

from Td.V_TEST_PERS;
Quit;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I  asked the same question the SAS Communities Forum  and I am glad to say that  i did find a Solution to this Problem.

Please see the link below :

https://communities.sas.com/t5/Base-SAS-Programming/Using-a-Teradata-UDF-in-SAS-Implicit-Sql-Pass-Thru/m-p/266850/highlight/false#M52685

Comment: Interesting workaround. Clever. Surprised by the use of an `ORDER BY 1` to get it to work.

Answer (score 1):

In your implicit SQL you reference the view with the LIBNAME alias `TD`, however when you reference the UDF you are not aliasing the `TEST` database containing the UDF with the LIBNAME alias. Syntactically, you may not be able to do that in SAS. (e.g. `TD.TEST.PTY_DECRYPT()` - in fact I wouldn't expect this to work)

The UDF may need to be placed in `SYSLIB` or `TD_SYSFNLIB` so that it is in a default search path for the database optimizer to find the UDF without being fully qualified. (e.g. `TD_WEEK_BEGIN()`) Alternatively, the UDF could be placed in database `SAMPLE` but that likely violates how UDFs are maintained in your environment, as it would in my environment.

Otherwise, the UDF call could be embedded in a view on the database, but then you have other issues to consider with the security of that column if your environment is not granting security on a column level basis to views containing encrypted data elements. (e.g. PHI, PII, etc.) Without a row-column level security mechanism in place to dynamically filter a users ability to see the column you are decrypting in the view putting the UDF into the view isn't going to work.